# xcode 8 xcodebuild manual code signing from command line for multiple provision profiles

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

In Xcode 7 I was building project through command line for multiple provision profiles by using following commands. I have multiple provision profiles and multiple code signing certificate linked to those profiles so I need to sign the IPA file with appropriate provision profile.

```
PROVISION_PROFILE="My Provision profile name"

xcodebuild -workspace ../ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme "${PRODUCT_NAME}" -sdk iphoneos -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" archive -archivePath "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.xcarchive"

xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.xcarchive" -exportPath "${BINDIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME}-${CURVERSION}.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "${PROVISION_PROFILE}"
```

Now these commands not working for Xcode 8. I uncheck the automatically manage signing after that it gives below error

"someProjectName" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'
Anybody please help me in this.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what the "Signing" section looks like in your project's target settings in Xcode, under General->Signing? It sounds like your Debug configuration doesn't have a provisioning profile set in the project file.

Comment: Right, I haven't added provision profile in that section because I want to build this from command line. Because I have multiple provision profiles for different configurations so I need to pass them from command line. Do you know how can I pass them from command line ?

Comment: @kgaleman Is this necessary to pass this info from project editor ?

Answer (score 0):

You are only specifying the provisioning profile in your `-exportArchive` command. In the `-workspace` command, Xcodebuild is reaching into the `-scheme` you specify, which looks at the `project.pbxproj` file and grabs the provisioning profiles you placed from the project editor for the configurations specified by the scheme being built.

If you open your `project.pbxproj` file in a text editor, you'll see that the Debug configuration has no provisioning profile listed, which is why Xcodebuild is throwing this error. To fix this, add your provisioning profiles in the project editor (or in `project.pbxproj`) for the configurations being built by your scheme.

Edit: Now that I better understand the requirements, editing my answer with another option. You can also do this to manually specify the provisioning profile in your build step:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ../ProjectName.xcworkspace -scheme "${PRODUCT_NAME}" -sdk iphoneos -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" archive -archivePath "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.xcarchive" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISION_PROFILE}"
```

Comment: Adding provision profile in project editor fixing the problem of throwing this error. I have different provision profile for different customers so I want to replace this provision profile in next step. 
Is -exportProvisioningProfile work in next step and replace the default profile ?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Guarav! I've edited my answer with another option for you. Let me know if that works.

Comment: before archiving there is one more step that I have not added in my question
xcodebuild -workspace project.xcworkspace -configuration Debug  -scheme Release-something clean build -destination generic/platform=iOS
If I add PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISION_PROFILE}" in this command then archive fails .
at what time exactly xcode needs these provision profies ? at build time or  archiving time or signing time  ?

Comment: @Guarav, this is hard to debug when we can't see the full set of steps you're following in your build and the error text that you're getting. Provisioning profiles and code signing is very tricky with not very clear documentation, so the more information we can get, the better.